# ErrorHandler not handling Error in Angular2

Tags: angular, error-handling

HI I have a custom error handler written in my Angular2 project.Its able to handle all http service call related errors, but when I throw a custom error its not handled rather logged in the console.

```
throw new Error('Custom Error here');

@Injectable()
export class MyCustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {  
   constructor( private service:ErrorService) {}
 //this is not reached when i throw like above
// I bootstraped this class  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyCustomErrorHandler}   
   handleError(error:any) {    
      console.error('handle error here '+JSON.stringify(error));      
   }  
}
```

Comment: Where did you throw it? Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Thank you @Günter Zöchbauer , actually am catching it any Component and instead of throwing the error, am throwing a customized error  throw new Error("custom error message'), I will try to write it on Plunker.

Comment: What do you mean with "I bootstrapped this class"? `bootstrap()` is outdated. It should be added to providers of `@NgModule(...)class AppModule()`